# Playing a raw audio file on a git hub pages project

Tags: audio

So, I just deployed a project on github pages. It includes audio files that it is not picking up. I tried to get them with a raw link like so:

(audio id="playAstring")
        (source src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TJacks89/Tune-Planet/gh-pages/sounds/Astandard.m4a" type="audio/mp4")
      (/audio)

and it is giving me this error message:

"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

Any ideas?

Comment: oh, and gh-pages in the link is the name of the branch, in case you were wondering.

Comment: Not sure what help you are looking from SO... Have you verified that file is actually present where you expect it?

Comment: The audio file? yes.

Comment: Clearly file you posted as sample is not there (404). I really doubt anyone will be able to help you with that amount of information... On other hand your post may have value for other visitors - so if you find the problem consider posting self-answer (if it is indeed real problem and not some spelling error).